# CallBack функции в консольном приложении C++

Tags: windows, c++

Если в консольном приложении ожидается ввод с клавиатуры (cin<<) а в этот момент происходит вызов Callback функции этого приложения из вне, то будет ли она вызвана!? Или здесь необходимо использовать многопоточное программирование?!

**Добавлено.**

```
#include "dde_server_for_quik.h"
#include "iostream.h"

int main()
{  
    char **ArrNameTabs;
    unsigned int AmountTabs;
    char *NameTab_1="DDE_TAB_BIDASSK";
    char *NameTab_2="tab2";
    AmountTabs=2;
    ArrNameTabs=new char *[AmountTabs];
    ArrNameTabs[0]=NameTab_1;
    ArrNameTabs[1]=NameTab_2;

    int Result;
    Result=InitServerDDE(ArrNameTabs,AmountTabs);
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    return(0);
}

HDDEDATA EXPENTRY DdeCallback(UINT wType, UINT fmt, HCONV hConv, HSZ hsz1, HSZ hsz2, HDDEDATA hData, DWORD dwData1, DWORD dwData2) 
{
    m1:
    goto m1;
}
```

**Добавлено.**

Это тестовое консольное приложение, тестируется сам DDE сервер, код находится в другом cpp файле, при помощи функции InitServerDDE происходит его инициализация, DdeCallback также находится в другом файле, в процессе инициализации адрес DdeCallback передаётся в WINAPI, и когда клиент пытается подключится (к примеру) к DDE серверу, эта функция должна быть вызвана (я так понимаю, при помощи ОС). В теле DdeCallback конечно же не бесконечный цикл! - это я пытался выяснить передаётся ли туда управление (если да, то ядро загрузится на 100%), но управление увы не передаётся! Быть может потому, что основной (и единственный) поток занят обработкой cin! И Винда не может передать управление другой функции в этом же потоке!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итого. Как я понял, из материалов MSDN, для работы DDE необходим цикл обработки оконных сообщений. Т.е. без цикла

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

который и занимается выборкой и обработкой сообщений, у нас DDE работать не будет. Так что консольное приложение не рассчитано на работу в качестве DDE-сервера :-(

Comment: Но ведь возможно этот цикл организовать и в консольном приложении!? А если запустить обработку сообщения не в главном потоке а во вторичном потоке(CreateThread)?

Comment: <i>А если запустить обработку сообщения не в главном потоке а во вторичном потоке(CreateThread)?</i><p>
Попробуйте. НО! Смысла в этом не очень много - представьте себе, что основной поток закончиться раньше. Хотя если в нем сделать ожидание пользовательского действия - возможно и заработает. Не знаю как соотнесутся cin и сообщения WM_*

Comment: Если я правильно понял консольный ввод работает правильно, а Callback() не вызывается ? А если попробовать цикл c GetMessage() после cin>>a <Enter>?
Опобликуйте результат, пожалуйста. Выполнился ли Callback().
Вообще, меня тоже интересует, какую технику программирования надо использовать в Винде для контролируемого прерывания чтения с консоли,
можно  ли сделать это без дополнительных потоков. Я пытался запрограммировать что-то такое для таймера (там у меня Сallback вызывался, но чтение не прерывалось), но целеустремленности (в изучении Винды) не хватило.

Comment: <i>контролируемого прерывания чтения с консоли, можно ли сделать это без дополнительных потоков</i>:<p>
Боюсь, что вариантов два:<p>
- использование неблокирующего ввода с консоли (например, kbhit());<p>
- использование второго потока.

Comment: avp: цикл c GetMessage() после cin>>a <enter>, то конечно работает! Просто cin блокирует основной и единственный поток не давая шансов CallBack`у! Теперь решил не использовать консоль, пишу оконное WIN32 приложение через WINAPI, благо не требуется навороченный графический интерфейс!

Comment: Спасибо, @rejie, наверное Вы правы. @gecube Спасибо ! А при использовании kbhit() (кстати, getch() это то же самое ? Он тоже не блокируется) для GetMessage() приходит ли сообщение и если да, то как его узнать ?
Вообще, как в Винде можно обобщить select(), чтобы отлавливать сокеты, консоль и таймаут. А то родной в Винде только для сокетов.

Comment: getch() - ждет ввода символа с клавиатуры. Так что разницы с cin>> скорее всего не будет. А kbhit() просто проверяет нажата ли клавиша в текущий момент времени.